# ¿Porque la caja SELECT2 se hace pequeña en un modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Reciban mi cordial saludo, para pedirle de su colaboración, debido a que presente el siguiente inconveniente al utilizar select2 en mi MODAL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El recuadro de select se hace demasiado pequeño, adjunto el código selecet.

```
<div class="row"> 


                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                     <div class="form-group">



                            <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">          


                            <option value="ASENCIO REBAZA ANNETTE - NEXUS"><strong>ASENCIO REBAZA ANNETTE - NEXUS </strong></option>
                            <option value="ARTEAGA ZAVALETA SEFORA - ESC"><strong>ARTEAGA ZAVALETA SEFORA - ESC</strong></option>
                            <option value="LUCIANO SALAZAR FRANCO - PLLAS"><strong>LUCIANO SALAZAR FRANCO - PLLAS</strong></option>


                            </select> 


                    </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui el query, por lo visto debe ser un tema de CSS pero necesito de vuestro apoyo para saber una posible solución.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

Comment: Echale un ojo a la documentación oficial: https://select2.org/appearance la librería tiene parametros para establecer el width que necesites

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya logré conseguir , gracias a tu comentario Fergush, muchas gracias nuevamente. Sabes como podría colocarlo pero en la parte de abajo del TEXTO ESPECIALISTA.

Comment: Solo tendrías que poner un <br/> delante del <label> de "Especialista", o en su defecto, por como veo tu código, detrás del <select class=...>

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente Fergush, gracias por el apoyo.